# How to use patch request with parameters in custom rest resource?

Tags: 9

I am creating a custom rest resource.

```
/**
 * Provides a resource to update nodes.
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "my_custom_resource",
 *   label = @Translation("Custom rest resource"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/custom-api/{node}",
 *   }
 * )
 */
class MyCustomResource extends ResourceBase {

  public function patch(EntityInterface $entity, $data = []): ResourceResponse {
    return new ResourceResponse('Some message', 200);
  }

}
```

But when I try to send a patch request from my postman using the URL `http://mysite/custom-api/2169`, I am getting an error

```
RuntimeException: Callable "Drupal\my_module\Plugin\rest\resource\MyCustomResource::patch" requires a value for the "$entity" argument. in Drupal\Component\Utility\ArgumentsResolver->handleUnresolvedArgument() (regel 143 van /var/www/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/ArgumentsResolver.php).
```

What can be the problem? How can I get the argument?

Answer (score 1):

Your canonical url should be `"/custom-api/{entity}"`

Comment: still I get this error. `RuntimeException: Callable "Drupal\paddle_webservice_api\Plugin\rest\resource\AddNodeTranslation::patch" requires a value for the "$entity" argument. in Drupal\Component\Utility\ArgumentsResolver->handleUnresolvedArgument() (regel 143 van /var/www/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/ArgumentsResolver.php).`

Comment: If I do not use it as a object of EntityInterface then when I print the $entity variable, it prints the node id which I pass in the url.

Comment: Right, it won't be the full entity, just the value passed, you should validate the value and load the entity in your patch function.